# Number of subsets of the set of 1s and 0s

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a 1,000 element set with 600 1's and 400 0's. How many subsets are there such that there are more 1's than 0's in the subset?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: My friend gave me this problem. My thought was to find a general formula by taking small cases (i.e. 5 element set, 3 1's 2 0's, as it seems like the 1 to 0 ratio is 3-2), but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: So what was your answer for the small case and how did you calculate it?  Even better, try six $1$s and four $0$s as it might be more instructive, which I make $6+5+4+3+2 = 20$ possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the $1$'s are indistinguishable from each other, and similarly for the $0$'s. Thus, each unique subset is completely determined by how many $1$'s or $0$'s it contains. Let $\alpha = (\alpha_{0}, \alpha_{1})$ denote the number of $0$'s and $1$'s in a given subset.

I would start by counting how many subsets there are with a fixed number of $0$'s. Then add them up for each possible number of $0$'s. Given that $\alpha_{0} = k \geq 0$, it is pretty clear that there are $600 - k$ possibilities for $\alpha_{1}$ ($\alpha_{1} \in \{k+1, \ldots, 600\}$). Thus,
$$|\{ \alpha  :   0 \leq \alpha_{0} \leq 400, \alpha_{0} < \alpha_{1} \leq 600 \}| = \sum_{k=0}^{400}(600-k) = 401(600) - 400(401)/2 = 401(400)$$